# communication between processes

Tags: c, linux, ipc

i have 4 processes say p1.p2,p3,p4..process p1 has to send a signal to p2 that it got init and that signal has to catch by p2 then it has to get init ...and p3 and p4 process has to get signal from p2 after its init then these process has to get init.........

can u suggest the logic in doing this or if possible sample code

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have 1,2,3,4. Then:

- 1-init->2
- 2-init->3,4

Right?

I would just directly send signals. Where is your problem?
In C you have to include signal.h and have to specify a handler subroutine for required signal (e.g. SIGUSR1).